# How to setup a proper navigation property using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a .NET MVC website, and I'm having some trouble with loading and saving related tables in my database through entity framework.

1) When i try to access a related entity from one table, my navigation property seem to be empty even though it shouldnt?

```
public class Table1 {
    public int Table1ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Table2")]
    public int Table2ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Table2ID")]
    public virtual Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
}

public class Table2 {
    public int Table2ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
}
```

I have my mapping like this in my EF context class:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>().HasOptional(u => u.Table1).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

In my controller i fetch the wanted Table2 instance and send it to my View:

```
public ViewResult Edit(int productId) {
    Table2 Table2Instance = repository.Table2.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Table2ID == productId);
    return View(Table2Instance);
}
```

In my view i need to do an action depending if the Table2Instance has a relation to Table1 or not, which i try to do like this:

```
@model Entities.Table2

@if (Model.Table1 == null && Model.Table2ID != 0){
    //Do this
}else if (Model.Table1 != null && Model.Table2ID != 0) {
    //Do that
}
```

But it seems like my navigation property doesnt work properly, since it will always show Model.Table1 as null even if the database has a relation.
How should i set up this navigation property right?

2) When i try to save a new Table1 property with context.Table1.Add(Table1Instance) and then context.SaveChanges() i get an error, because it tries to save the Table1ID as 0 everytime and does not increment?

Answer (score 2):

The related navigation properties are not read by default. To read them you can use:

- lazy loading (i.e. accessing the property when `LazyLoading` is enabled)
- eager loading (i.e. using `Include`)
- explicit loading (it's a bitmore complicated)

In your case, the more appropriate solution is eager loading, which is done like this:

```
Table2 Table2Instance = repository
  .Table2
  .Include(t2 => t2.Table1) // add this to your query
  .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Table2ID == productId);
```

As to the second question, you should show more code. You must be aware that in a layered application, when your entity gets out of the `DbContext` you have to attach it back, and set the entity status before calling `SaveChanges`.

Comment: I think that it's worth noting that the strongly-typed include example here also requires `using System.Data.Entity;`.

Comment: in the controller, even though im using System.Data.Entity, im getting an error when using .Include inside my action method Edit? It says IEnumerable<Entities.Table2> doesnt contain a definition for include

Comment: Quite strange, it's an extension method from DbExtensions class, which is in the System.Data.Entity namespace. Is repository an object of a class that inherit from DbContext? is Table2 and IQueryable<Table2>? If you type DbExtensions in your file is it recognized as an existing class?

Comment: My repository is made from my interface ITable2Repository which inherits from my EFTable2Repository which creates an repository object which inherits rom DbContext

Comment: In my controller it wont recognize DbExtensions, but other Db classes such as DbConfiguration, DbContext

Comment: Which EF version are you using? It makes no sense... This class is on the main EF assembly: EntityFramework.dll

Comment: fairly new i think: 6.1.0

Answer (score 0):

> because it tries to save the Table1ID as 0 everytime and does not increment?

You need to include setting a column as an Identity column:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>()
  .HasOptional(u => u.Table1)
  .WithRequired()
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>()
  .Property(x => x.Table2ID )
  .StoreGeneratedPattern = StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity;
```

Comment: it says that .StoreGeneratedPattern does not exists in that context